# Omnisharp atom deprecations

Tags: .net, macos, mono, atom-editor, omnisharp

I'm getting this deprecations in atom is it normal? should I do something?

[omnisharp deprecations](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b1raecsqhwem73i/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202015-04-02%2019.30.48.png?dl=0)

I cannot get the omnisharp server to run because says that mono is not found...

[mono error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/107bbxkbemzg93f/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202015-04-02%2019.31.00.png?dl=0)

Comment: You just need to install Mono 3.4.0 or above and make sure that it is on your path.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-atom/wiki

They say it clearly in "Runtime prerequisites" that you need to install Mono runtime separately but you don't.

Comment: Mono definitely *is* required right now if you're not on Windows. That will change in the future.